# Embeber documento em pdf e ativar scroll para submeter

Tags: php, jquery, pdf, rolamento

Bom dia, 
gostava de embeber um documento em pdf no meu site para uma ficha de inscrição em PHP, em que após puxar o scroll até ao fim do pdf, ativa-se o botão de submeter. Eis o código, estou usando jquery para buscar o estado do scrool, mas não estou conseguindo.

```
echo '<embed src="ficha.pdf" width="600" height="200" type="application/pdf"  class="pdfrender">';
```

//jquery

```
$(".pdfrender").on("scroll", function(){ alert("OK");   });
```

Comment: O que acontece? Dá algum erro? Se sim, qual? Apenas não funciona? Funciona, mas não gera o resultado esperado? Qual resultado teve? Qual era o esperado?

Comment: ele não retorna o alert ao mexer no scroll.